# How to darken the light for the whole scene in PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, lighting, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am making a game in PyOpenGL and I want to let the light to be darkened when the player dies. How can I do that?

I've tried several resources like [Tweak the brightness/gamma of the whole scene in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139012/tweak-the-brightness-gamma-of-the-whole-scene-in-opengl) and https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/535812-disable-opengl-lighting-completely-to-dark-scene/ with no luck.

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

#[...]

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1])
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1])

#[...]

while True:

    #[...]

            glClearColor(0.53, 0.63, 0.98, 1) #Change background colour (sky blue)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    #[...]

    if health <= 0:
        pass #this is where the darkening should go
        #---Tried---
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT1)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT2)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT3)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT4)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT5)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT6)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT7)
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, @mat_specular)
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, @mat_shininess)
        glLightModelfv( GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, @globala )

        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        #---Tried---
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I expected the scene to be dark, but instead it returns a traceback about decorators. Even if I delete these, nothing changes on my scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reduce the RGB values for the ambient an diffuse light ( see [`glLight`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLight.xml)). e.g.:

```py
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1])
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1])
```

The ambient light is applied to t all surfaces independent on the position or the direction of the light. The diffus light depends on the position respectively direction of the light and the normal vector ([`glNormal`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormal.xml)) of the surface.

The light color is multiplied by the current color (because of `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)`) and the ambient, diffuse and specular light are summed.

The standard OpenGL [Blinn-Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_shading_model) light model is calcualted like this:

```
Ka ... ambient material
Kd ... difusse material
Ks ... specular material

La ... ambient light
Ld ... diffuse light
Ls ... specular light
sh ... shininess

N  ... norlmal vector 
L  ... light vector (from the vertex position to the light) 
V  ... view vector (from the vertex position to the eye)

Id    = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);

H     = normalize(V + L);
NdotH = max(dot(N, H), 0.0);
Is    = pow(NdotH, sh);

fs    = Ka*La + Id*Kd*Ld + Is*Ks*Ls;
```